# why isn't the jquery validation running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, upload

I have this form with all other inputs and all inputs are showing the error correctly except this one, which is a file upload.

Can someone give me a pair of eyes and see where I got it wrong?

When I `console.log(element)` which is suppose to show when the error happens but it didn't even happen at all.

this is the code for my html

```
<label for="phone">Phone</label><input type="text" name="phone" value="">
<label for="city">City</label><input type="text" name="city" value="">
<label for="qr_code_image">QR CODE</label><input type="file"  class="hidden image-field" name="qr_code_image" id="qr_code_image"><div class="add-image-icon" data-field="qr_code_image"><i class="icon-plus"></i></div>
```

in my js

```
           rules: {
                city: {
                    required: true
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                },
                qr_code_image: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            // Where to place the error message
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                console.log(element);
                error.appendTo(element.next('.errorMsg'));
            }
```

I didnt' add the divs for the error output here.
with the console log, I can only see two errors instead of 3.
I tried submitting without even clicking the image upload though.

Edit: I realised those two classes are both using `display: none !important`

Is there a way to keep the css and still make the validation to work?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe .hidden is added as default fields to be ignored. You can override the "ignore" fields with something like: '$("#myform").validate({
   ignore: ".ignore"
});'

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I tried deleting the hidden class too and still doesn't work, thought of that too :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
qr_code_image: {
  required: true,
  accept: "image/jpeg, image/pjpeg"
}
```

Comment: accept / extension isn't really the problem though, even require wouldn't work.

Comment: please check your code in that page html. maybe you using `qr_code_image` as class or id on other div (element).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form').validate({
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
           city: {
                required: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
            },
            qr_code_image: {
                required: true,
                accept: 'jpeg|png|jpeg'
            }
        },
         // Where to place the error message
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            console.log(element);
            error.appendTo(element.next('.errorMsg'));
        }
    });

});
```

add the `ignore:[]` field in the options might fix the problem.i also faced a similar problem doing that fixed the issue.

Comment: no luck :( what does the ignore field do? and days just getting weirder... accept field won't let me accept another than one format